# QGIS Python Dialog Box for Zooming into coordinates

Tags: pyqgis

```
qid = QInputDialog()
title = "Enter Coordinates"
label = "X:" 
mode = QLineEdit.Normal    
text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(qid, title, label, mode)
print text
```

I am trying to create a dialog box in which I can zoom into specific coordinates. However, I'm not sure on how to get both X and the Y coordinates. The picture below shows only X.

[image: Current Dialog Box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a basic example using `QInputDialog` for make zoom to input coordinates

```
qid = QInputDialog()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
input, ok = QInputDialog.getText( qid, "Enter Coordinates", "Enter New Coordinates as 'xcoord,ycoord'", QLineEdit.Normal, "X" + "," + "Y")
if ok:
    x = input.split( "," )[ 0 ]
    print x
    y = input.split( "," )[ 1 ]
    print y
    if not x:
        print "Ooops!X value is missing!"
    if not y:
        print "Ooops!Y value is missing!"
    print x + "," + y
    scale=50
    rect = QgsRectangle(float(x)-scale,float(y)-scale,float(x)+scale,float(y)+scale)
    canvas.setExtent(rect)
    pt = QgsPoint(float(x),float(y))
    canvas.refresh()
```

Sample coord,for example is : **-418795,4911670**

Comment: Thanks for this. I am geting an error "Global name 'iface' is not defined. I then added self.iface = iface but it doesnt seem to like that either. :(

Comment: put this `qgis.utils.iface`

Comment: No luck! NameError: global name 'qgis' is not defined

Comment: import this  `from qgis.utils import *`

Comment: It's still giving the same error!

Comment: are you execute this code in a plugin?

Comment: if you put `from qgis.utils import *` and after only use iface. works perfectly

Comment: Yes it is to execute. Where did you put qgis.utils.iface? I've put it in the def __init__  like:

def __init__(self, iface):
    # save reference to the QGIS interface
    qgis.utils.iface
    self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

but that is throwing an error.

Comment: I managed to fix the error! It works! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

QInputDialog is designed to get a single value. Is you want a more advanced input you should use a form.

You have an example on how to create a form in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325531/how-can-i-validate-and-exit-qinputdialog) (to a similar question).

Answer (score 1):

`QInputDialog()` only gets a single value as explained in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html). One option is to change the label to "coordinates". The user could then enter both x and y in one line, separated by a comma. You can then get the individual values by using python.

```
x = text.split(",")[0]
y = text.split(",")[1]
```